# Delay between messages Azure Botframework virtual assistant - skill

Tags: azure, botframework, delay, azure-bot-service

I am working on a virtual assistant and skill. When trying to add delays in messages send by the skill like below, it will work when connecting to the skill directly (using a token or webchat), but when calling the skill through the virtual assistant, it will send a typing indicator for a short moment, but the delay is gone.

I am using directLine for this in browser and see the same result using the emulator and webchat in portal.azure.com.

```
await context.sendActivities([
   { type: 'typing' },
   { type: 'delay', value: 2000 },
   { type: 'message', text: 'Hello... How are you?' }
]);
```

Does someone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What is setup in the VA for typing? Is it the default `Use(new ShowTypingMiddleware());` ? This is set in DefaultAdapter.cs. The default uses a 500 delay and 2000 period.

Comment: @DanaV It is using that middleware (set up in TypeScript) this.use(new ShowTypingMiddleware());